# Measuring code complexity of functional language and imperative language

Tags: functional-programming, complexity-theory, measure

What is the best way of comparing code complexity of functional language and imperative language?

In my case I have to compare complexity of certain programs written in F# and C++.
As for now as a code quality measure I am using lines of source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "best" way. There is not even a remotely acceptable way.

- SLoC (and related measurements, like character count) are utterly meaningless; refer to Wikipedia for a summary of the most common criticisms
- if you want a more abstract thing to count, like "atomic elements" of the program, you got to decide what you consider such - and many will disagree, rightfully so, because this matter is mostly undecidable
- Also, such comparisions are rarley fair because most of them use example problems that tend to be solved more naturally in one language or the other. Every tried implementing an [Accumulator Factory](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Accumulator_factory) in C++? Now remember that the problem was proposed by a Lisp advocate (Paul Graham)...
- Moreover, many would argue that really clever solution which uses very few lines/characters/"atomic elements" isn't the best solution in any otherway - look at code golf

All things considered, the best solution might be taking many different real-world problems, solving them idiomatically in different languages, and just informally looking at the source and deciding which looks more elegant.

Comment: LOC has obvious merit because it measures how much code there is to read.